# React Native web view onShouldStartLoadWithRequest not working android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to open url in an inAppBrowser but onShouldStartLoadWithRequest is not working for android. I have tried setting setSupportMultipleWindows to false and also used onNavigationStateChange and both of them are not working as expected. Is there any work around for this?

```
  const onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (request: WebViewNavigation) => {
    if (request.navigationType === 'click') {
      console.log('clicked')
      openInAppBrowser(request.url);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```